# Finding the needle in the Haystack using C

Tags: c

I'm having troubling figuring out why not my code is not iterating through the if statement until it finds the correct character.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char * my_strstr(char * param_1, char * param_2) {
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = 0; param_1[i] != '\0'; i++) {
      printf("this is a loop for j %c\n", param_1[i]);
      for (j = 0; param_2[j] != '\0'; j++) {
        printf("this is a loop for j %c\n", param_2[j]);
        if (param_1[i] == param_2[j]) {
          printf("figuring out this %c\n", param_1[i]);
          j++;
          i++;
          return &param_1[i];
          printf("figuring out this %c\n", param_1[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  }

int main() {
  char * param_1 = "hello";
  char * param_2 = "ello";

  printf("This is the string %s \n", my_strstr(param_1, param_2));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: When the if statement is true (found a single matching character), the function returns.  It will never try to match more than that first character.  What do you expect to happen different?

Comment: The `printf()` after the `return` is pointless — it will never be executed.

Comment: In the inner loop, you need to break the loop if the characters are different.  After the loop, you return only if you reached the end of `param_2`.  And you should be comparing `param_1[i + j]` with `param_2[j]`, should you not?

Comment: what do you mean by finding correct character what do you expect it to print?

Comment: @ChrisDodd I ultimately want it to return all of the matching characters. Example if param_1 = "Hello" and param_2 = "ello", I would want the return to  all of the matching characters in the first string

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Oh that makes sense! Thanks!

Comment: @ColinJackson "needle ,Haystack" is descriptive.  Consider using those names instead of `param_1,  param_2`.

Comment: @ColinJackson "I would want the return to all of the matching characters in the first string" --> Simpler to just return the address in _haystack_ of the beginning of the match.  Calling code knowns the length, it has the needle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've pasted your code below with some edits and comments I hope will help.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char * my_strstr(char * param_1, char * param_2) {
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = 0; param_1[i] != '\0'; i++) {

      // this should say "loop for i" shouldn't it?
      printf("this is a loop for j %c\n", param_1[i]);

      // use a flag to determine if you have found a match or not
      int found = 1;

      for (j = 0; param_2[j] != '\0'; j++) {

        /* you actually want to compare param_1[i + j] == param_2[j] here
           (respecting bounds of course). */
         if (! param_1[i + j] || param_1[i + j] != param_2[j]) {
           found = 0;
           break;
          }

        printf("this is a loop for j %c\n", param_2[j]);

        /* i don't understand what the following code was meant to do but you will
           rarely want to increment i and j outside of the for ()

        if (param_1[i] == param_2[j]) {
          printf("figuring out this %c\n", param_1[i]);
          j++;
          i++;
          return &param_1[i];
          printf("figuring out this %c\n", param_1[i]);
        }
        */
      }

      // here you want to check if you found it, and return if so.
      if (found) {
        return &param_1[i];
      }
    }
    // need a default for if it is never found:
    return NULL;
  }

int main() {
  char * param_1 = "hello";
  char * param_2 = "ello";

  printf("This is the string %s \n", my_strstr(param_1, param_2));

  return 0;
}
```